# Can't send auth headers with axios

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

Can't send authorization header with rest API. Got 'OPTIONS' error with status 0. All headers and options are allowed on the server. Server is written on PHP.

Here is my request:

```
axios.post(`${API_URL}users/${23}/profile/main/update`,
    {formData},{
    headers:{ 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    Authorization:`Bearer ${token}`}
    })
```

It seems like it does not send the header when there is authorization. However, it works, if i delete authorization, and leave only content type
[image]

Comment: Did you try the same using `$.ajax`?

Comment: no, can you help with the code using Ajax?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
axios({
 method: 'POST',
 url:`${API_URL}users/${23}/profile/main/update`,
 headers: { 
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`},
 data: formData
})
```

Refer [docs for browser](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send as below:

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
}

axios.post(`${API_URL}users/${23}/profile/main/update`,
{formData}, headers)
```

Try using Ajax call below:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$.ajax({
  url:`${API_URL}users/${23}/profile/main/update`,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data : formData,
  method : "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, it is possible that you are not passing the sent auth header from your apache config to your php application.
you might need to set

> WSGIPassAuthorization On

inside your virtualhost config.

[Check this](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html)

Comment: Is it the problem on front end? Im using reactJS, is there any configuration like this?

Comment: @NateRiver No you'll have to set this up on the server.